# Question regarding Von-Mangoldt function.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\psi(x) := \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n)$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the Von-Mangoldt function.
I want to show that if $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x} =1 $$ then also $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(x) \log x }{x}=1.$$

I tried to play a little bit with $\psi$, what I want to show is that:

$$\left| \frac{\pi(x) \log x}{x} -1 \right| \leq \left| \frac{\psi(x)}{x} -1 \right| \rightarrow 0$$

So I tried to develop $\psi$ a little bit, but I got astray.

So I have 
$$ \frac{\psi(x)}{x} -1 = \sum_{p^k \leq x , k \geq 1} \frac{\log p}{x} -1 = \frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{p\leq x} \log p + \sum_{p^2\leq x} \log p + ...+ \sum_{p^k \leq x, p^{k+1} >x} \log p \right) -1 $$
and I want to estimate its aboslute value from below, but I don't have any idea?

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First instead of $\psi(x)$, we will deal in terms of $\theta(x)$ because of the following reason.

Clearly $$\psi(x) \geq \theta(x).$$
Further,
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi(x) & = \sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda(n) = \sum_{\overset{p^k \leq x}{p \text{ is a prime and }k \in \mathbb{Z}^+}} \log(p)\\
& = \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p \text{ is a prime}}} \log(p) + \sum_{\overset{p^2 \leq x}{p \text{ is a prime}}} \log(p) + \sum_{\overset{p^3 \leq x}{p \text{ is a prime}}} \log(p)  + \cdots\\
& = \theta(x) + \theta(x^{1/2}) + \theta(x^{1/3}) + \theta(x^{1/4}) \cdots\\
& \leq \theta(x) + \frac{x^{1/2} \log(x)}{2} + \frac{x^{1/3} \log(x)}{3} + \frac{x^{1/4} \log(x)}{4} + \cdots\\
& = \theta(x) + \log(x) \left( \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor \log_2(x) \rfloor} \frac{x^{1/k}}{k} \right)\\
& \leq \theta(x) + x^{1/2} \log(x) \left( \sum_{k=2}^{\lfloor \log_2(x) \rfloor} \frac1k \right)\\
& = \theta(x) + \mathcal{O} \left(x^{1/2} \log(x) \log(\log(x))\right)
\end{align*}
$$

Hence, if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x} = 1$, then so is $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\theta(x)}{x} = 1$.

Further $\displaystyle \theta(x) = \sum_{\overset{p \leq x}{p \text{ is a prime}}} \log(p) = \sum_{2 \leq n \leq x} \log(n) (\pi(n) - \pi(n-1))$ i.e.

$$d \theta (x) = \log(x) d\pi(x)$$
Hence, we have that $\displaystyle d \pi(x) = \frac{d \theta(x)}{\log(x)}$. Since $\theta(x) = x + o(x)$ we get that $$\pi(x) = \int_{2^-}^{x} \frac{d \theta(t)}{\log(t)} = \int_{2^-}^{x} \frac{d t}{\log(t)} + \mathcal{O} \left( \int_{2^-}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log^3(t)} \right)= \frac{x}{\log(x)} + \mathcal{O} \left( \frac{x}{\log^3(x)} \right).$$

Comment: Can somebody elaborate how the term $\mathcal{O} \left( \int_{2^-}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log^3(t)} \right)$ is obtained in the final line?

Answer (score 5):

This is a modification of a proof given in Chandrasekharan's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* (p.65, Theorem 2).  Since you ask for hints I'll try to leave out some of the details and retain the landmarks.

As you noted, we have

$$
\psi(x) = \sum_{p\leq x} \log p + \sum_{p^2\leq x} \log p + \sum_{p^3\leq x} \log p + \cdots,
$$

the chain of sums being finite for $x > 0$ since $p^m \geq 2^m > x$ when $m > \log x/\log 2$.  Now, if $x \geq 1$ and $p^n \leq x < p^{n+1}$, then $\log p$ occurs exactly $n$ times in the sum, and $n = \lfloor \log x / \log p \rfloor$.  Thus

$$
\psi(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \left\lfloor\frac{\log x}{\log p}\right\rfloor\log p.
$$

The result then follows in two steps.  First, show that

$$
\psi(x) \leq \pi(x) \log x.
$$

Next, let $0 < \alpha < 1$, and show that

$$
\psi(x) \geq \sum_{x^\alpha < p \leq x} \left\lfloor\frac{\log x}{\log p}\right\rfloor\log p \geq \alpha \log x (\pi(x) - x^\alpha),
$$

then divide by $x$ and let $x \to \infty$.