# Additional book for Introduction to analytic number theory (Apostol)

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I am studying analytic number theory by the book of Tom Apostol. I find the book rather abstract (and difficult). Could anyone advise me an additional book that is more concrete in its examples?

Joe

Comment: I hate to pick on you, but can you give an example of an example from Apostol's book that you found less concrete than desirable?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153081/589 and the other answers there.

Comment: @uniquesolution: Starting with theorem 1.2 (especially the proof). Already found a discussion on MSE. Theorem 1.13 (p18)Theorem 1.15 (p20).  And starting in chapter 2, theorem 2.1 did it all. I really haven't the slightest idea what is going on in there. What I need - to understand - is examples with real number.

Comment: @Ihf: thanks for the link!